# IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider did not rise

Tags: c#, iis, ftp

I've realized curom authentication for ftp site basing on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2011/06/30/how-to-create-an-authentication-provider-for-ftp-7-5-using-blogengine-nets-xml-membership-files/, but `IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider.GetUserHomeDirectoryData` did not rise

```
public class FtpEngineNetAuthentication : BaseProvider,
    IFtpAuthenticationProvider
    , IFtpRoleProvider
    , IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider
    , IFtpPostprocessProvider
    , IFtpLogProvider
{
    private readonly string _logfile = Path.Combine(@"c:\test", "logs", "FtpExtension.log");
    private string _dbConnectionString;
    private string _ftpHomeDirectory;
    protected override void Initialize(StringDictionary config)
    {
       // Retrieve the paths from the configuration dictionary.
       _dbConnectionString = config["RextorConnectionString"];
       _ftpHomeDirectory = config["ftpHomeDirectory"];
    }

    bool TryGetUser(string login, out User user)
    {
       user = null;
       try
       {
          using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectionString))
          {
             var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName, Password, HashAlgorithm, PasswordSalt FROM Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord WHERE UserName = @login", conn);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
             conn.Open();
             using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if (reader.Read()) // Don't assume we have any rows.
                 {
                    user = new User()
                    {
                       Login = reader.GetString(0),
                       Password = reader.GetString(1),
                       HashAlgorithm = reader.GetString(2),
                       PasswordSalt = reader.GetString(3)
                     };
                  }
              }
              conn.Close();
          }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {

         return false;
     }

  return true;
}

    // Define the GetUserHomeDirectoryData method.
    string IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider.GetUserHomeDirectoryData(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName)
    {
        // Test if the path to the home directory is empty.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ftpHomeDirectory))
        {
            // Throw an exception if the path is missing or empty.
            throw new ArgumentException(@"Missing ftpHomeDirectory value in configuration.");
        }
        LogMessage($"directory: {userName}");
        var result = $@"{_ftpHomeDirectory}\{userName}";
        LogMessage(result);
        // Return the path to the home directory.
        return result;
    }

    // Define the AuthenticateUser method.
    bool IFtpAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUser(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userPassword, out string canonicalUserName)
    {

        // Define the canonical user name.
        canonicalUserName = userName.Replace("@", "").Replace(".", "");
        // Validate that the user name and password are not empty.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(userPassword))
        {
            // Return false (authentication failed) if either are empty.
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            // Create a user object.
            User user = null;
            // Test if the user name is in the dictionary of users.
            if (TryGetUser(userName, out user))
            {

                var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(user.PasswordSalt);
                // Retrieve a sequence of bytes for the password.
                bool isValid;
                if (user.HashAlgorithm == "PBKDF2")
                {
                    LogMessage($"user password: {user.Password}");
                    LogMessage($"user salt: {user.PasswordSalt}");
                    LogMessage($"user salt&pwd: {Encoding.Unicode.GetString(CombineSaltAndPassword(saltBytes, userPassword))}");
                    // We can't reuse ComputeHashBase64 as the internally generated salt repeated calls to Crypto.HashPassword() return different results.
                    isValid = true;
                    //Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Password, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(CombineSaltAndPassword(saltBytes, userPassword)));
                    //PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(user.Password, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(CombineSaltAndPassword(saltBytes, userPassword)));
                    //BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(user.Password, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(CombineSaltAndPassword(saltBytes, userPassword)));
                }
                else
                {
                    isValid = SecureStringEquality(user.Password, ComputeHashBase64(user.HashAlgorithm, saltBytes, userPassword));
                }

                //if (isValid && user.HashAlgorithm != DefaultHashAlgorithm)
                //{
                //    var keepOldConfiguration = _appConfigurationAccessor.GetConfiguration("Orchard.Users.KeepOldPasswordHash");
                //    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keepOldConfiguration) || keepOldConfiguration.Equals("false", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                //    {
                //        user.HashAlgorithm = DefaultHashAlgorithm;
                //        user.Password = ComputeHashBase64(user.HashAlgorithm, saltBytes, userPassword);
                //    }
                //}
                return isValid;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex.Message);
            // Raise an exception if an error occurs.
            throw new ProviderException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);

        }
        // Return false (authentication failed) if authentication fails to this point.
        return false;
    }
    bool IFtpRoleProvider.IsUserInRole(string sessionId, string siteName,string userName, string userRole)
    {
        LogMessage($"check role: {userName} - {userRole}");
        return true;
    }

    public FtpProcessStatus HandlePostprocess(FtpPostprocessParameters postProcessParameters)
    {
        LogMessage("Running Post Process");  //this message never appears
        return FtpProcessStatus.FtpProcessContinue;
    }

    public void Log(FtpLogEntry logEntry)
    {
        //LogMessage(logEntry.);
    }
    private void LogMessage(string logEntry)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_logfile, true))
        {
            // Retrieve the current date and time for the log entry.
            var dt = DateTime.Now;

            sw.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\tMESSAGE:{2}",
                dt.ToShortDateString(),
                dt.ToLongTimeString(),
                logEntry);
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does 'rise' mean?

Comment: did not fires, executed

Comment: Where is it called?

Comment: this is extension class for ftp in iis server. ftp server must call it